# Twitch API not showing full information

Tags: vb.net, api, twitch

I am currently using vb.net to pull some channel information from the twitch api.
This is successful.. sometimes.
Other times i get half data about a channel.

Here is the relevant snippet of my code

```
Dim json As String = GetHTML(New Uri("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=" & channels & "&limit=1000"))
Dim root As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim follows As JToken = root("streams")

    For Each twitch_name As JToken In follows
        Dim name As String = twitch_name("channel")("display_name").ToString()
        Dim viewers As String = twitch_name("viewers")

        Dim partner As String = "False"
        Dim status As String = "Unknown"
        Dim cover As String = "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Unknown-92x128.jpg"

        'Added this to band-aid the issue
        If twitch_name("channel")("partner") Then
            partner = twitch_name("channel")("partner").ToString()
            status = twitch_name("channel")("status").ToString()
            cover = "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/" & twitch_name("channel")("game").ToString() & "-92x128.jpg"
        End If

        'Do stuff with that info
    Next
```

As i said before, this work flawlessly most of the time. But sometime the channel data get omitted for some strange reason.

Here is what the channel json should look like

```
    "channel": {
        "_links": {
            "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/official_don_gaming",
            "follows": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/official_don_gaming/follows",
            "commercial": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/official_don_gaming/commercial",
            "stream_key": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/official_don_gaming/stream_key",
            "chat": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/official_don_gaming",
            "features": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/official_don_gaming/features",
            "subscriptions": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/official_don_gaming/subscriptions",
            "editors": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/official_don_gaming/editors",
            "videos": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/official_don_gaming/videos",
            "teams": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/official_don_gaming/teams"
        },
        "background": null,
        "banner": null,
        "broadcaster_language": "en",
        "display_name": "Official_DoN_Gaming",
        "game": "Grand Theft Auto V",
        "logo": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/official_don_gaming-profile_image-bbad92a4240c21b3-300x300.png",
        "mature": true,
        "status": "[GIVEAWAY] $10 Million Challenge & RACES- w/ SUBS n viewers - SUB GOAL 0/5",
        "partner": true,
        "url": "http://www.twitch.tv/official_don_gaming",
        "video_banner": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/official_don_gaming-channel_offline_image-0302a62c10304fb1-640x360.png",
        "_id": 62679916,
        "name": "official_don_gaming",
        "created_at": "2014-05-16T10:58:17Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-03-26T15:16:24Z",
        "delay": 0,
        "followers": 30943,
        "profile_banner": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/official_don_gaming-profile_banner-2b68918de5679c47-480.png",
        "profile_banner_background_color": "#000000",
        "views": 162014,
        "language": "en"
    }
```

And this is what i get sometimes (Doesn't always happen with the same channel, it's just random)

```
"channel": {
    "_id": 62679916,
    "name": "official_don_gaming",
    "created_at": "2014-05-16T10:58:17Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-03-26T15:16:24Z",
    "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/official_don_gaming"
    },
    "display_name": "Official_DoN_Gaming",
    "logo": "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/official_don_gaming-profile_image-bbad92a4240c21b3-300x300.png",
    "bio": "Official DoN Gaming started as a Pro Battlefield team, but i have now switched it over to full time streaming and hope to bring you as many new games as possible.",
    "type": "user"
}
```

As you can see, it seems to be going to the */users/* url instead of the */channels/* url. Some insight as to why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated.